# With JXA, where does the 'aliases' come from in the System Events Application?

Tags: javascript-automation

I would be very grateful for an explanation. Specifically:

I don't see any Terminology for 'aliases' in any Script Dictionary but the following example works:

```
var items = systemEvents.aliases.byName(sourcePath).diskItems;
```

Where is this magic described? I would be very grateful for an explanation of where these (and the logged) object properties come from.

```
    var currentApp = Application.currentApplication();
    currentApp.includeStandardAdditions = true;
    var systemEvents = Application("System Events");

    // Ask user to choose a folder

    var sourcePath = currentApp.chooseFolder ({
        withPrompt: "Choose the source folder"
    }).toString();

    var items = systemEvents.aliases.byName(sourcePath).diskItems;

    var selectedItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      if (item.class() != "folder" && item.visible()) {
        selectedItems.push(item.name());
        console.log("file : " + item.name().toString());
      }
    }
```

I am scouring the Javascript Script Dictionaries, the [JavaScript for Automation Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW1) etc. etc. but cannot find an explanation of the `app` object properties appearing in this log.

```
        app = Application("Script Editor")
        app.chooseFolder({withPrompt:"Choose the source folder"})
            --> Path("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb")
    app = Application("System Events")
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.length
            --> 8
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(0).class()
            --> "file"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(0).visible()
            --> true
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(0).name()
            --> "Real Book in Bb Vol 3.pdf"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(0).name()
            --> "Real Book in Bb Vol 3.pdf"
    /* file : Real Book in Bb Vol 3.pdf */
    app = Application("System Events")
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.length
            --> 8
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(1).class()
            --> "file"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(1).visible()
            --> true
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(1).name()
            --> "Real Book In Bb Vol 2.pdf"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(1).name()
            --> "Real Book In Bb Vol 2.pdf"
    /* file : Real Book In Bb Vol 2.pdf */
    app = Application("System Events")
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.length
            --> 8
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(2).class()
            --> "file"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(2).visible()
            --> true
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(2).name()
            --> "The New Real Book vol 2 Bb.pdf"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(2).name()
            --> "The New Real Book vol 2 Bb.pdf"
    /* file : The New Real Book vol 2 Bb.pdf */
    app = Application("System Events")
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.length
            --> 8
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(3).class()
            --> "file"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(3).visible()
            --> true
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(3).name()
            --> "The New Real Book vol 3 Bb.PDF"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(3).name()
            --> "The New Real Book vol 3 Bb.PDF"
    /* file : The New Real Book vol 3 Bb.PDF */
    app = Application("System Events")
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.length
            --> 8
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(4).class()
            --> "file"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(4).visible()
            --> true
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(4).name()
            --> "Real Book In Bb Vol 1 (Fifth Edition).pdf"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(4).name()
            --> "Real Book In Bb Vol 1 (Fifth Edition).pdf"
    /* file : Real Book In Bb Vol 1 (Fifth Edition).pdf */
    app = Application("System Events")
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.length
            --> 8
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(5).class()
            --> "file"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(5).visible()
            --> true
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(5).name()
            --> "masternx.pdf"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(5).name()
            --> "masternx.pdf"
    /* file : masternx.pdf */
    app = Application("System Events")
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.length
            --> 8
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(6).class()
            --> "file"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(6).visible()
            --> true
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(6).name()
            --> "The New Real Book vol 1 Bb.PDF"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(6).name()
            --> "The New Real Book vol 1 Bb.PDF"
    /* file : The New Real Book vol 1 Bb.PDF */
    app = Application("System Events")
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.length
            --> 8
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(7).class()
            --> "file"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(7).visible()
            --> true
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(7).name()
            --> "Charlie Parker - Omnibook.pdf"
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.at(7).name()
            --> "Charlie Parker - Omnibook.pdf"
    /* file : Charlie Parker - Omnibook.pdf */
    app = Application("System Events")
        app.aliases.byName("/Users/iain/Documents/Music/Real Books/Real Books in Bb").diskItems.length
            --> 8
    Result:
    undefined
```

Comment: Against close votes: JXA is just as on-topic as AppleScript.